# How to integrate spring-batch in Wildfly

Tags: spring-batch, wildfly

Does anyone know how to integrate spring-batch into a standalone wildfly (8.x)
instead of jberet ??

I tried to follow the instructions on this page : http://www.radcortez.com/spring-batch-as-wildfly-module/

I disabled all the Arquillian stuff and was able to run mvn process-resources
but when im trying to run mvn wildfly:execute-commands -P install-spring-batch im getting an error :

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.1.Final:execute-commands (default-cli) on project wildfly-spring-batch: Execution default-cli of goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.1.Final:execute-commands failed: Failed to process file 'C:\workspace\spring-batch\target\scripts\wildfly-add-spring-batch.cli': Command execution failed for command '    --resources=${wildfly.module.classpath}'. Failed to locate C:\workspace\spring-batch\${wildfly.module.classpath}

My understanding was that these path's would be generated during the run, but i will have to investigate further

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions on this page : http://www.radcortez.com/spring-batch-as-wildfly-module/
but im not quite sure about the instructions  - if the shown pom file should be integrated into a project pom file or it should be a complete standalone pom file

Comment: Have you looked in the github repo associated with that blog post: https://github.com/radcortez/wildfly-spring-batch

Comment: Yes i did - it didnt help me that much